# Creating Apache Mod_Rewrite Rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been trying for the past couple of days to get some rewrite rules working, but have been unsuccessful.

In my application, I have a directory structure of /App/Users/Create.php (for example) and what I would like to do is have the browser view as /App/Users/Create/.

I have tried the following with virtual host files and .htaccess but it will not serve the page the way I would like it to:

```
(1)RewriteRule ^App/Users/Create/$ /App/Users/Create.php [L]
(2)RewriteRule ^App/([A-Za-z]+)/Create/$ /App/$1/Create.php [L]
(3)RewriteRule ^Create/$ Create.php [L]
```

None of these have worked so far, so I was hoping that I could get some help from you guys. I have looked for some answers on here, and haven't found exactly what I was looking for, and have looked at Mod_Rewrite tutorials and URL rewriting tutorials from Google and even Bing searches trying to figure this out.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: how does it "not work"?

Comment: When I request /App/Users/Create/ it sends 404 Not Found errors each time

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_rewrite loaded and a `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: Yes they are both on. I have a two other rewrite rules that are working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Slashes can get into the wrong places. So can path fragments.

I would rewrite rule #1 like this:

```
RewriteRule ^App/Users/Create/?$ App/Users/Create.php [DPI,L]
```

Rule #2 (note that you would do either rule 1 or rule 2, but not both):

```
RewriteRule ^App/([A-Za-z]+)/Create/?$ App/$1/Create.php [DPI,L]
```

Rule #3:

```
RewriteRule ^Create/?$ Create.php [L]
```

Comment: Each of these still gave me a 404 response code, even when I tried in both the Virtual Host configuration and in an .htaccess file.

Comment: Well, does `App/Users/Create.php` exist? What happens if you try to access it directly?

Comment: It exists and the page serves correctly if accessed directly.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 in case you have a weird cache problem, also change the request url slightly.

Comment: Still having the same problem, I went and looked at the Apache access log and it tells me that "-" was returned when I request /App/Users/Create/.

Comment: You're using rule 1 or 2 but not both, right? Anyway it shouldn't matter. Sorry, but I'm out of ideas. :(

Comment: I am using rule #1 right now. No problem, have been scratching my head the last couple of days with this, couple more won't hurt too much, lol.

Comment: Maybe @anubhava will look at it and see the problem, he's much more experienced than me.